# Is there a 'filter:hashtags' in the Twitter Stream API?

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

I'd like to only retrieve tweets that contain any hashtag in the Twitter Stream API. In the Search API, this can be done using 'filter:hashtags'.

I am using the locations filter and would like to also get tweets that contain the '#' character. Currently I get all tweets and I'd like to filter out the ones that do not contain a '#'. The 'term=#' doesn't seem to work.

Found this stale thread on the twitter dev forums https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18787.

At this point I'm assuming it can't be done through the Stream API.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't such a feature in the Streaming API.

You can refer to the [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters) for a complete list of the available request parameters.